# Creating a JSON file (keys)

Tags: objective-c, json, serialization

In my app I upload data using JSON in the following way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *titles = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (UITextField *textField in messagename)
{
    [titles setObject: textField.text forKey: @"title"];
    // as you can see, here you're replacing the value @ at key "title" with a new object on every pass
}

NSMutableDictionary *message = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (UITextField *textField in messagetext)
{
    [message setObject: textField.text forKey: @"title"];
    // as you can see, here you're replacing the value @ at key "title" with a new object on every pass
}

NSMutableDictionary *all = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (UITextField *textField in messagename)
{
    [all setObject: titles forKey: message];
    // as you can see, here you're replacing the value @ at key "title" with a new object on every pass
}

NSString *jsonString = [all JSONRepresentation];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[jsonData writeToFile: getImagePath atomically: YES];


NSString *destDir = @"/sandbox/";
[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                withParentRev:nil fromPath:getImagePath];
```

the only problem is that only the text for the last created table is uploaded, not all. I used the tags with cases, but it was too long , and If an object was nil, the app crashed.
Also, I can only upload "message", or "message name" separately with this result:

```
{"title":"Untitledjjjj"}
```

The whole purpose of the "all" was to have something like: message1 (main key) with under key title, with corresponding title, and message with corresponding message. then message2...

How can I do this?? If I upload all the result is {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same key all the time.. probably you should use an array instead for both `titles` and `message`.

I will just fix the first part, that should be enough:

```
NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];

for (UITextField *textField in messagename)
{
    // add textfield contents to array
    [titles addObject: textField.text];
}
```

Do you get it? In a dictionary, one key can only have one value. So you are always replacing the contents with each call of `[dicitonary setObject: ... forKey: @"title"];`